# Excel number in column - first available for product

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem to be solved in Excel. I have two columns in Excel. The y column is made up of numbers or sections. The x column must be the result of a revaluation of the first number available in the y column. Once the first value has been obtained, in the x column there must be another cell which will be the revaluation of the second available number of the column y. I have to write the formula in x and then pull it down, without the possibility of changing it. how can I do?

example

[image]

As you can see from the image the number 9059.26 is the result of 9000*(1+x) etc. Where the number 9082.03 is written is incorrect, as it always points to 9000, instead I need to point to 22559.26 and then re -evaluate it. and so on? can you help me? Thank you I tried this formula but it is not right for the recursive concept but only for the first one value in y column :

```
=IFNA(IF(E3=H3;0;IFS(AND(Q3<>"-";INDEX(BM:BM;MATCH(TRUE;ISNUMBER(BM:BM);0)));INDEX(BM:BM;MATCH(TRUE;ISNUMBER(BM:BM);0))*(1+Input!$C$10)^((Q3-VLOOKUP('Calcolo Massivo Hoja1'!B3;Perimetro!$B:$C;2;0))/365);AND(R3<>"-";INDEX(BM:BM;MATCH(TRUE;ISNUMBER(BM:BM);0)));INDEX(BM:BM;MATCH(TRUE;ISNUMBER(BM:BM);0))*(1+Input!$C$10)^((R3-VLOOKUP('Calcolo Massivo Hoja1'!B3;Perimetro!$B:$C;2;0))/365)));"-")
```

I  want the right result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgUo2.png)

second screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAq39.png)

third screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QrW3.png)

4th screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyIKe.png)

5ht screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePnr6.png)

6th screen: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYRRf.png)

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do: how did `9000*(1+x) resulted in 9059,26 when there is no 59.26 in x? Put in a bit more effort into explaining the logic you want applied. The formula you tried refers to columns E,H,Q,BM, etc, we can't glean anything from it.

Comment: sorry, It is a different formula but I want only the logic. I have to do the process explained in the topic. As you can see from the image the number 9059.26 in the column X  is the result of 9000*(1+i)  where i is a rate. etc. The number 9082.03 is written is incorrect, because it points to 9000, instead I need to point to 22559.26 and then re -evaluate it for the rate i. and so on, ok?

Answer (score 0):

To show the logic of what you are trying to do (and hopefully this is **NOT** an `xy problem`),
try:

```
A1: =IF(B1 = "", "", IF(ROWS($B$1:B1) = 1, 0, LOOKUP(2, 1 / ISNUMBER(INDEX($B$1:B1, SEQUENCE(ROWS($B$1:B1) - 1))), INDEX($B$1:B1, SEQUENCE(ROWS($B$1:B1) - 1))) * (1 + Rate)))
```

and fill down

If your version of Excel has the `LET` function, you can shorten it a bit:

```
A1: =LET(rng, INDEX($B$1:B1, SEQUENCE(ROWS($B$1:B1) - 1)), IF(B1 = "", "", IF(ROWS($B$1:B1) = 1, 0, LOOKUP(2, 1 / ISNUMBER(rng), rng) * (1 + Rate))))
```

The formula uses the

- `LOOKUP` function to find the last number existing in the range starting with `B1` and ending with the row prior to the row where the formula exists.
- Then there are some checks for a blank cell in the adjacent column or being the first row of the range.
- If the cells in the adjacent column might just be non-numeric, then just change the section
  `B1 = ""` to `NOT(ISNUMBER(B1))` or whatever test you require to produce a blank result.

If you have an older version of Excel, you can try:

```
=IF(B1 = "", "", IF(ROWS($B$1:B1) = 1, 0, LOOKUP(2, 1 / ISNUMBER(INDEX($B$1:B1, ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A, ROWS($A$1:A1) - 1)))), INDEX($B$1:B1, ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A, ROWS($A$1:A1) - 1)))) * (1 + Rate)))
```

You may need to enter this as an array formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256428/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-rosenfeld-excel-number-in-column-first-available-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.